# Does mysql update query rebuild index on column with updating same value again and again?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a update query which updates two columns of table. Most if the time one column have same value and it is indexed.
So my question is - It will be slower or I need to separate the update query for these columns.

Answer (score 1):

A single update is better, regardless.  `UPDATE` is smart enough to notice that no change happens.